# for each in blocking collection

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, blockingqueue

Suppose I have an instance of LinkedBlockingQueue queue; and  want to use for each with this queue:

```
for(Object obj : queue)  {

//do smth
}
```

How will this code behave in case if queue is empty at the moment? Will it block the running until queue will become not empty or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not block, it simply does not enter in the loop branch.

You can easily check:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
for (Object obj : queue) {
    System.out.println("Inside the loop, is empty? " + queue.isEmpty());
}
System.out.println("Not blocking, is empty? " + queue.isEmpty());
```

Output: `Not blocking, is empty? true`

Comment: hahahah :-) I've already tested the same code but with another message

Answer (score 3):

No, it would not block ([demo](http://ideone.com/KuddUJ)).

Java's `for`-each loop gets the `iterator` from the collection, and uses that iterator to traverse the collection. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#iterator%28%29), the iterator of `LinkedBlockingQueue<T>` collection reflects the state of the queue at the time the iterator is constructed:

> The returned iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator.

Since the queue is empty at the time the iterator is constructed, the iterator would not wait for more data to become available, and report that it has no additional elements. Of course, if the collection becomes non-empty after the construction of the iterator, the iterator *may* return some of the newly inserted items.